# How can I get an image button's dimensions to make sense in android?

Tags: android, layout, position, imagebutton, dimensions

First of all, can I just say, I find laying out android UI's to be a frustrating experience? I used to think the XML layouts were simple and clean and awesome but every time I try to make anything with it I spend hours trying to do the simplest things!

In this particular instance I'm trying to make a simple horizontal bar that contains an image button of fixed size on the right and to the left of it I want an ImageView that takes up the rest of the available width.  I see similar constructs all the time in the UI: the search box that appears at the top of the screen when searching, the text area and send button for composing text/googletalk messages, etc.

I've tried both a horizontal linear layout and a relative layout, and I can't get the button to look right in either one. My latest attempt has the following layout code:

It looks like this:

[image: Screnshot]

Using the hiearchyviewer indicates that both the imageview and the button have the same height (45px).  And it shows the view dimensions and positions to be exactly what I'm looking for.  Same height (differing widths of course since the ImageView is much wider). And they butt right up next to each other, centered in the Relative Layout.  However the button as drawn on screen is obviously not taking up the full ImageButton view.  I'm thinking it's something weird about the android system 9patch drawable used for the ImageButton background. But what do I know? I can't get it to look right no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you set up your `RelativeLayout`? Try to set it up like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:id="@+id/imgButton"></ImageButton>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:src="@drawable/red_button" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgButton" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgButton" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgButton"></ImageView>        
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That layout results in the proper dimensions and positions for the views in the hierarchy viewer as I mentioned before but the button still doesn't have the right dimensions when viewed on the device. I've since decided to make my own nine-patch drawable for the button background and that seems to have worked.  It would appear that the system nine-patch button drawable has some padding on the bottom in the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

If dimensions are exactly how you are looking for , then in ImageButton and ImageView , use android:scaleType="fitXY" and check.

For simple case , I might use linearlayout with horizontal orientation with two buttons in it with proper weights.

Comment: You'd think it would be as simple as that wouldn't you? I've managed to get the button background to be the right size now but I can't get the image to center in the ImageButton, it always appears at the top.  I've tried fitXY and it still doesn't center.